# Load audio file with PHP and play with JS

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load a wave audio-file with php and play the audio with javascript.

My Javascript code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'php/test.php', true); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    var audio = new Audio("data:audio/wave;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText))));
    audio.play();
  }
}
xmlhttp.send(url);
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
  readfile("test.wav");
?>
```

Unfortunately it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Be more explicit by what happens exactly. I.e. what do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Comment: I don't get any javascript errors and the audio file isn't playing. I also tested the php-script on command-line and get the content of the wave-file. The response-text of the php script seems to be OK, I'm not quite sure if the encoding is working.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var audio = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + escape(btoa(xmlhttp.responseText)))
```

And you can just point the AJAX request directly to the `.wav` file.

Comment: I've already tried this before, but btoa results in a javascript error: "String contains an invalid character".